# Problem with NSMutableArray and custom NSObject

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, null

I'm really desperate on this one. I'm trying to make a Framework which you can search and play YouTube videos with. But while testing it, I'm running in to a big problem.

In the search operation I'm adding YTVideos (a subclass of NSObject) to a NSMutableArray. When I loop thru it in the main(), I'm getting nil-objects:

**Method**

```
- (NSArray *)videosInRange:(NSRange)range {
 if(range.length > 50) {
  [NSException raise:@"Range lenth > 50"
     format:@"The range of -videosInRange: can't be bigger than 50"];
  return nil;
 }

 if((range.location + range.length) > 999) {
  [NSException raise:@"Range to big" 
     format:@"The given range was to big (%d, %d)", range.location, range.length];
  return nil;
 }

 NSString *searchURLString = [[self feedURL] absoluteString];
 searchURLString = [searchURLString stringBySettingURLAttribute:@"start-index" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",range.location + 1]];
 searchURLString = [searchURLString stringBySettingURLAttribute:@"max-results" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",range.length]];

 NSLog(@"%@",searchURLString);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURLString];
 NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
                 options:0
                   error:NULL];
 if(!xmlDoc)
  return nil;

 NSArray *videoElements = [[xmlDoc rootElement] elementsForName:@"entry"];
 NSMutableArray *videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[videoElements count]];
 register int i;
 for(i = 0; i < [videoElements count]; i++) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *addPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  YTVideo *vid = [[YTVideo alloc] initWithXMLElement:[videoElements objectAtIndex:i]];
  [videos addObject:vid];
  [vid release];

  [addPool drain];
 }

 NSArray *retValue = [NSArray arrayWithArray:videos];
 [videos release];
 return retValue;
}
```

**main()**

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 YTSearchFeed *feed = [[YTSearchFeed alloc] initWithSearch:@"Eminem"];
 long long results = [feed videoCount];
 NSLog(@"%lld videos for search", results);

 long long i = 0;
 while(results != 0) {
  int length = (results >= 50) ? (50) : (results);

  NSArray *videos = [feed videosInRange:NSMakeRange(i, length)];
  NSLog(@"L: %d", [videos count]);
  int z;
  for(z = 0; z < [videos count]; z++, i++) {
   YTVideo *vid = [videos objectAtIndex:z];
   NSString *title = [vid title];
   NSLog(@"%d: %@", i+1, title);
  }

  results -= length;
 }

 [pool drain];

 return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

I hope someone can take the time to look at this, and if you need anymore information, just ask.

Thank you in advance,
ief2

**EDIT: YTVideo**

```
- (id)initWithXMLElement:(NSXMLElement *)element {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        _XMLElement = [element copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    if(!_title) {
        NSString *str = [[[self XMLElement] firstElementWithName:@"title"] stringValue];
        _title = [[str stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] retain];
    }

    return [[_title copy] autorelease];
}
```

I get the title (and other video information) only when it's requested. the -stringByDecodingHTMLEntities works fine (Category on NSString).

Comment: Maybe just the title is nil? I think there may be an issue with your `initWithXMLElement ` method in `YTVideo`. Can we see the `YTVideo` class?

Comment: What exactly do you see as output from this program? Does it print `"nil"`, or `"(null)"`?

Comment: It prints (null), but another thing I've noticed, when I insert a break-statement at the end of the while loop in main(), the program crashes. The debugger's log:
"2 main; 1 NSPopAutoreleasePool; 0 objc_msgSend". If you want me to upload the whole project, I'm certainly willing to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the code and initialized all instance variables in the `-init`method